# Retrieve from the store for time and set it to minvalue

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        data: [
            { name: 'Lisa', phone: '555-111-1224', timecallval: '08:10' },
            { name: 'Bart', phone: '555-222-1234', timecallval: '09:54' },
            { name: 'Homer', phone: '555-222-1244', timecallval: '20:00' },
            { name: 'Marge', phone: '555-222-1254', timecallval: '08:11' }
        ]
    });


var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
           items: [
            {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                name: 'timecall',
                id: 'timecall',
                minvalue: '08:00' 
                // 08:00 to be changed to timecall value dynamically
            }
}
```

I have searched for quite awhile but i don't seem to be able to set minvalue as the value retrieved from store. The problem is I want timefield to display 08:10, 09:54, 20:00 and 08:11 for selection. Any helpers?

Comment: Did you try [`setMinValue`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-method-setMinValue)?

Comment: Yes. I did reset: function () { {Ext.Date.format(Ext.getCmp('reserveStartTime'), 'H:i:s');} @DrakeEnterpriseSystems but it did not work..

Comment: @DrakeEnterpriseSystems setMinValue works already. Was adding in the wrong method for setMinValue

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

Ext.getCmp('reserveEndTime').setMaxValue(selectrow.get('timecall'));